# What is the best way to find a function to closely approximate this data?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with Python and linear regression, but can't seem to find a way to generate an accurate function. The following graph was generated from a 1000 element list of values.

I have tried Skicit-learn, but I can't get it to actually learn and improve the estimate.

Ideally, the function will closely mirror the graph. The graph itself is blatantly sinusoidal, so I imagine that this might be straightforward.

[image]

Comment: did you try to approximate it with `RandomForestRegressor` from `sklearn.ensemble`? I've used this in a tutorial with data that looked very similar to yours. I can't seem to find the tutorial right now; I'll update if I finde it.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure I understand your question: do you need an analytical function or just an `(x, y)` numerical representation of your data?

Comment: Also, perhaps it would be more useful to actually show your trials, maybe you are already half-way there.

Comment: @MrFuppes I have not. I will look into that, I appreciate it.

Comment: @norok2 Preferably some sort of trigonometric function that, when plotted in the graph above, closely follows its trajectory. I am dealing with a camera that is swaying back and forth. I picked a point to track in each image, and plotted that point's X coordinate. My goal is to use the generated analytical function to compensate for this sway.

Comment: @EliCox analytical it may be though. Most methods assume you have a model function for which you adjust the parameters. Perhaps a sum of harmonic functions would do the trick, perhaps not. In that case, you may want to look into `scipy.optimize` (e.g. `.curve_fit()` or `.least_squares()`). Alternatively, you may use `np.polyfit()` but I would not expect great results from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example for the `RandomForestRegressor` It's based on a tutorial I did to learn, so intellectual property might belong to somebody else. If anybody knows the proper reference, please comment/edit!

I think this fits your data - however I'd like to add that this creates/trains a random forest model, not a function in the sense of a physical description of the process that generates the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
x = 10 * rng.rand(200)

def model(x, sigma=0.3):
    fast_oscillation = np.sin(5 * x)
    slow_oscillation = np.sin(0.5 * x)
    noise = sigma * rng.randn(len(x))
    return slow_oscillation + fast_oscillation + noise

y = model(x)

forest = RandomForestRegressor(200)
forest.fit(x[:, None], y)

xfit = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
yfit = forest.predict(xfit[:, None])
ytrue = model(xfit, sigma=0)

plt.errorbar(x, y, 0.3, fmt='o', alpha=0.6)
plt.plot(xfit, yfit, '-r')
plt.plot(xfit, ytrue, '-k', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: I can definitely adapt my data to this. Thank you so much

Comment: @EliCox, maybe play around with the number of trees etc. a bit, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) for more info.